# Quadratic variation of $X_t=\int_0^t B_s \, ds$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, quadratic-variation

Let $B$ be a standard brownian motion and
$$
X_t=\int_0^t B_s \, ds.
$$
What is the quadratic variation  $[X]_t$ of $X$?

I see $dX_t$ as an sde with drift term $B_t$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$[X]=0$ since $X$ has [finite variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#Finite_variation_processes).

Comment: Hi! Could you maybe explain a little more why this is the case?