# Quadratic variation of $X_t=\int_0^t B_u \, du$

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

Let $(B_t)_t$ be a brownian motion and:
$$
X_t=\int_0^t B_u \, du.
$$
What is the quadratic variation  $<X>_t$ of $X$?

Comment: It is zero.  Can you see why?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236762/quadratic-variation-of-x-t-int-0t-b-s-ds?rq=1

Comment: I know that it's zero, but i can't see why.

Comment: What is your definition of quadratic variation?  What techniques do you know for computing it?

Comment: I need to compute $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \sum^{p}_{i=1}(X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}})^2 $ with $\delta = sup_i (t_i - t_{i-1})$, i can't see why it has a finite variation.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2793236/36150) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/727683/36150)